# Statistical conclusions from incompatible measurement results

Tags: bayesian, p-value, standard-deviation, credible-interval

I assume that the following situation is not uncommon in scientific practice:

1. Two research groups analyse two samples.
2. The reported results **concern the same physical quantity** at the same location and at the same time.
3. The analysis methodologies are different.
4. The reported results are calculated differently from the raw data that were measured.
5. **But**: The reported results are incompatible, i.e. the sum of their bell curves has two peaks, i.e. is bi-modal.

[image]

As a specific example one may consider the **atmospheric carbon dioxide concentration at the south pole**

- directly measured from atmosphere and
- measured by an ice core.

These are for example the time series from atmospheric measurements at the [south pole](https://cdiac.ess-dive.lbl.gov/trends/co2/sio-spl.html) compared to ice core  measurements at [Law Dome](https://cdiac.ess-dive.lbl.gov/trends/co2/lawdome.html):

[image]

When the two samples are not identical (as in the example: one sample was gaseous, the other sample was solid) the first guess to explain the discrepancy is by the difference of the samples (1). To exclude this (for the sake of my argument/question) let me assume that the samples are identical. Discrepancies may occur nevertheless.

The next guess then to explain the discrepancy is by the difference of measurement methodologies (3) and/or calculations (4). Let me assume that both seem sound for both research groups, so both measurements may have the same a priori credibility.

For the sake of simplicity let me assume that both standard deviations are the same.

Now I am at the heart of my question:

> - Which conclusions can be drawn from the two incompatible results (bell curves)?
> - How wrong must at least one of the results be (with respect to mean and standard deviation)?
> - What can be assumed to be the "true" mean and the "true" standard deviation?

Remember that two measurements (reported values) are supposed to be "incompatible" when the sum of their bell curves has two peaks, i.e. is bi-modal.

I further suppose that a measurement (a reported value) is "wrong" when the true value falls outside the two standard deviation interval of the reported mean.

Comment: Why have you chosen to define bimodal as "incompatible"? Why do you consider values more that one standard deviation from the mean as "wrong"? Nearly 1/3 of results would meet this criteria in a normal distribution.

Comment: I have to be more explicit about this. Bimodal = wrong in the case that there is only one "true" value - isn't this a (or even the) typical case?

Comment: I changed "one standard deviation" to  two standard deviation".

Comment: Why does being two standard deviations from the mean make a measurement wrong? Why does being four standard deviations from the mean make a measurement wrong? At least for a Gaussian distribution, points four standard deviations from the mean should happen $0.00633\%$ of the time. This is infrequent, sure, but they should happen from time to time.

Comment: Doesn't this change in the presence of a conflicting result (of equal credibility)?

Comment: This post appears to describe "systematic error" (a form of *measurement error* sometimes called "bias"--but beware the many different meanings of that term!)  All one can conclude in the generality with which this question is posed is that one or both of the measurement methods has detectable systematic error.  You don't describe any data, information, or assumptions to support conclusions about the correctness of either system.

Answer (score 1):

The question is interesting. I will use a simple example to illustrate what I believe the core idea is.

Let $y_i$ denote a noisy measurement of $x$ and let each measurement have its own measurement error. In particular, let
\begin{equation}
y_i = x + \varepsilon_i
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon_i \sim \textsf{N}(0,\sigma_i^2)$. We can re-express this as
\begin{equation}
p(y_i|x) = \textsf{N}(y_i|x,\sigma_i^2) . 
\end{equation}
Suppose we have two such measurements. The likelihood of $x$ is given by
\begin{equation}
p(y_1,y_2|x) = p(y_1|x)\,p(y_2|x) = \textsf{N}(y_1|x,\sigma_1^2)\, \textsf{N}(y_2|x,\sigma_2^2) .
\end{equation}
We can re-express the likelihood of $x$ as
\begin{equation}
p(y_1,y_2|x) \propto \textsf{N}(x|m,s^2) ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
m &= s^{2}\left(\frac{y_1}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{y_2}{\sigma_2^2}\right) \\
s^2 &= \left(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\right)^{-1} .
\end{align}

Thus, the likelihood of $x$ is unimodal regardless of how far apart the measurements are relative to their variances.

Now let us examine the likelihood of the ***model***. Let us assume the prior for $x$ is
\begin{equation}
p(x) = \textsf{N}(x|\mu,\tau^2) . 
\end{equation}
The likelihood of the model is given by
\begin{equation}
p(y_1,y_2) = \int p(y_1,y_2|x)\,p(x)\,dx = \frac{e^{-\frac{(m-\mu )^2}{2 \left(s^2+\tau
   ^2\right)}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{s^2+\tau
   ^2}}
\end{equation}

In order to simplify the exposition, let us assume the measurement errors are the same: $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = \sigma$. We also assume $y_1 \ne y_2$. Then,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\sigma\to 0}\ p(y_1,y_2) = 0 ,
\end{equation}
which means that in the limit the measurements are completely incompatible with the model.

A numerical illustration may prove helpful. Let $y_1 = 1$, $y_2 = -1$, $\mu = 0$, and $\tau = 1$. With these values,
\begin{equation}
p(y_1,y_2) = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}}}{2 \pi  \sigma 
   \sqrt{\sigma ^2+2}} .
\end{equation}
In this case,
\begin{equation}
p(y_1,y_2) \approx \begin{cases}
3\times 10^{-2} & \sigma = 1 \\
4\times 10^{-3} & \sigma = 1/2 \\
5\times 10^{-8} & \sigma = 1/4
\end{cases} . 
\end{equation}
The likelihood of the model falls off dramatically as $\sigma$ decreases from one. The model with $\sigma = 1/4$ is roughly one million times worse than the model with $\sigma = 1$.

If one is confident that $\sigma = 1/4$ is correct, then very likely there are other assumptions of the model that are incorrect. The way to procede then is to identify those parts of the model and correct them. For example, perhaps
\begin{align}
y_i &= \xi_i + \varepsilon_i \\
\xi_i &= x + u_i ,
\end{align}
where $u_i \sim \textsf{N}(0,\omega_i^2)$.

In any event, I think it is a mistake to try to horse-out the "truth" from a model that is so completely "false."